# How to create a web2py launcher icon?

Tags: 14.04, python

I have downloaded `web2py` which is sitting inside: `~/web2py/web2py.py`

How can I create a launcher for this?

Comment: Didn't help me: I can start it with "python ~/web2py/web2py.py"

Comment: Use `Exec=python /home/emedokles/web2py/web2py.py` and this [web2py logo](http://www.todobackend.com/images/logos/webpy.gif) as your icon image. Then follow the instructions in david6's answer to the linked question.

Comment: This starts web2py, as does my code above, but if I close it, it disappears from the launcher again. The mentioned link didn't help me.

Comment: @karel No, unfortunately it won't.

Comment: @Karel Hello, no I have no Icon in the dash. Web2py is resting in my home directory ('~/web2py/web2py.py'). I can start it via the terminal: 'python web2py/web2py.py'. If I do so the icon appears in the launcher but if I lock it there it will disappear as soon as I close web2py. Locking icons for icons I see in the Dash (like the terminal app) works.